# Solution concept in broad terms of optimal stopping?

Tags: stopping-time

I want to learn optimal stopping. I have read a little about it, but don't understand it quite fully.

I know that it is about finding $\sup_t E f(X_t)$ where $t$ is a stopping time.

My question is, what are the methods (IN BROAD TERMS, i.e. no specific mathematical details, just intuition) to calculate $E f(X_t)$ and then find supremum?

It would seem to require the joint distribution of $(X, t)$ for all stopping times $t$, otherwise we cannot calculate the expectation $Ef(X_t)$. But since stopping times $t$ can be of all sorts of types, it does not seem feasible to me to have a "general" approach to calculating this joint distribution?

So what else can we do? In discrete time, we can just do backwards dynamic programming, but what about continuous time and/or infinite horizon?